# Sequence formula every other row

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, sequence, array-formulas

I would need to use formula, which inserts numbers in sequence but into every other column. 
I found the formula `SEQUENCE`, which already inserts numbers as I need to, but in every column. Is it possible to make it so it skips every other column?

Example:
`=SEQUENCE(1,'Info'!C3,'Info'!D3,1)`

which will make numbers

`|1|2|3|4|5|`

I would need to make it like this:

`|1| |2| |3| |4| |5| |`

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISODD(COLUMN(1:1)), SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(1:1), 2, 1)/2, ))
```

[image: 0]